# Setting EVAL function in iMacros for calling out an URL after a certain number of LOOPS

Tags: loops, url, eval, imacros, goto

I am setting a macro to register accounts, but after every 10 signups it blocks registering because it exceeds the limit per IP per hour.

So, I need to make a call function with EVAL to go to my router url and resets my IP after 10 loops.

I got a premade source file with more than 2000 random logins and passwords for registering. I am looping this file so I can copy and paste 10 times the registering codes and then access my router url.

Here is a code i found to parse every 10 loops, but it is for waiting 120 secs.

```
SET longWait EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' % 11 == 0) ? 120 : 0")
URL GOTO={{longWait}}
```

This is my code so far for resetting ip every 1 loop but it takes some time to make every sign up because the router delay on resetting ip.

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=registeringurl.com
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE hopexregistro.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:M_Name CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:M_Email CONTENT={{!COL2}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:M_Password CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:form ATTR=NAME:M_Password2 CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV FORM=ID:form ATTR=TXT:Eu<SP>concordo<SP>com<SP>os<SP>termos<SP>de<SP>serviço<SP>e<SP>que<SP>tenho<SP>mais<SP>de<SP>13<SP>anos<SP>de<SP>idade.<SP>Você*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:form ATTR=ID:agree CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form ATTR=CLASS:normalButton
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form ATTR=CLASS:normalButton
WAIT SECONDS=7
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=http://192.168.0.1
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:login
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Status
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:disconnect
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=NAME:button
WAIT SECONDS=35
```

I appreciate your time and help. Thanks!

Comment: I believe that it would be much easier to find the list of free proxy IPs and to use the ‘iMacros’ command ‘PROXY ADDRESS’ than to reset your router (even after every 10 loops as you want).

Comment: And if I get a list of free proxy addresses, how would you suggest I set to change and use a proxy address every 10 loops?

Comment: You can add another column in your csv-file filled with these IPs: 1-10 rows – the first IP, 11-20 rows – the second IP etc. After reading it use the command `PROXY ADDRESS={{!COL4}}…` in the code. Note that it’s just a simple example of how I would suggest proceeding.